# Change VB6 cell properties on runtime?

Tags: vb6

I have a table with a foo number of rows and bar number of columns.

What i'd like is for the selected cell to really appear as being selected.

At the moment the leftmost cell gets a red text to mark it's being selected.

What i'd llike is for the lines at the top and bottom of the cell to get bigger to really show that the cell is selected.

I've looked at the following but without success.

```
grd.row = aRow
grd.col = aCol

' Therafter i try to change the following:
 grd.CellBorderColor = 255 ' Original value does not change 
 grd.CellBorderStyle = 2 ' Original value does not change
```

**EDIT:**

I found out that previously named properties are read only.. What can i do?

Any tips and/or pointers in the right direction will be highly appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: Are you using msflexgrid?

Comment: @AshReva I'm using vaSpread

Comment: If the properties are read-only, follow some other convention to indicate the current cell. Some thing like, changing background color of cell ... etc

Comment: @rags Setting the backgroundcolor of the cell works fine. These properties in particular does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular grid. Called `vaSpread` or `fpSpread` needs a specific line to execute.

For executing changes to grid style you need to call `grid.action = 13` after you've written the visual changes to the grid.